# useSession not returning data as expected

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

**UPDATE**

It works now. All I had to change is

```
session: {
  jwt: true,
  strategy: "jwt"
}
```

I am new in next-auth. I was practicing next-auth sign-in with credentials using MongoDB as a database. Whenever I sign in with credentials, useSession doesn't return data as expected but if sign in with other providers like google and GitHub it returns data as expected. Below I have given my code.

**[...nextauth.js] code:-**

```
export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const client = await connect();
        const usersCollection = client.db().collection("users");

        const user = await usersCollection.findOne({
          email: credentials.email,
        });

        if (!user) {
          client.close();
          throw new Error("No user found!");
        }

        const isValid = bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);

        if (!isValid) {
          client.close();
          throw new Error("Invalid password/email");
        }
        client.close();
        return user;
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      console.log(user)

      return session
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      // console.log(token)
      return token
    },
  },
});
```

**signIn logic:**

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const status = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      password: passwordRef.current.value,
      
    });
    console.log(status); // {error: null, status: 200, ok: true, url: 'http://localhost:3000/login'}
    console.log(session); // {data: null, status: 'unauthenticated'}
  };
```

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Where the variable `session` in your `console.log` comes from?

Comment: Const session=useSession()